# Android Studio, Junit cannot be resolved even after Junit4 added to classpath

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

How it happened

- the unit test class works fine initially.
- I encountered this issue after removing the C:\users\my_username\.Android\.gradle folder, and redirecting gradle dir in Android Studio to E:\Android_file_folder\gradle.

Since then, my unit tests cannot be compiled any more, although I have tried the following,

- Disabled work offline option
- Adding implementation 'junit:junit:4.12' to classpath
- In Android Studio, File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart
- Clean project and rebuild project

Problem Symptoms,

- annotation in unit tests (@Test, @Before, @After) is red. When pressing Alt+Enter over these annotaion, the pop up menu keeps giving me the option to add Junit4 to classpath.
- I check the gradle folder ( E:\Android_file_folder\gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\junit-4.12.jar\2509a789951ff3e52dd4785783415e3f ") it is empty.

Can you show me any additional steps I can try to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is resolved by doing the following,

- deleting the .gradle directory in the project directory.
- deleting the .idea\libraries
- sync gradle

It appeared that despite changing the service directory under **File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Gradle>Service Directory Path** alone without deleting the mentioned folders doesn't stop the project from looking in the old directory.